# Issues testing an Angular component

Tags: angular, testing

I have a component with the following initialization

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.transactionForm.get('type').valueChanges.subscribe(transType => {
            if (transType === 'xx') {
                this.transactionForm.patchValue({
                    subTotal: 0
                });
                console.log('done', this.transactionForm.value);
            }
        });
    }
```

And I am trying to write the following test:

```
it('should ...', () => {
            fixture.detectChanges();
            const expectedSubTotal = 0;
            comp.transactionForm.patchValue({
                type: 'xx',
                subTotal: 42
            });
            fixture.detectChanges();
            console.log('getting');
            const actual = comp.transactionForm.get('subTotal').value; // Does not get 0 - gets 42 instead
            expect(actual).toBe(expectedSubTotal);
        });
```

The `console.log`s all print the right value but I cannot seem to get this test to pass. What am I missing?

Comment: Angular executes `Object.keys(value).forEach['type', 'subTotal']` therefore `type` is changed then `subTotal` becames 0(changes event) and then `subTotal` becames 42. So it works as expected

Comment: How did it become 42 again?

Comment: `.patchValue({
                type: 'xx',
                subTotal: 42
            })`

Comment: So how do I get around that?

Comment: Reordering the patch fixed it. You are awesome!!. You can put that as an answer and I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that subscribers are executed synchronously during `form.patchValue`

```
.patchValue({ type: 'xx', subTotal: 42 });
                 (1)         (3)
                  ||
                  \/
                 (2)
    form.get('type').valueChanges.subscribe
```

Therefore either run

```
comp.transactionForm.get('type').updateValueAndValidity();
```

after patching or reorder your  properties

```
.patchValue({ subTotal: 42, type: 'xx' });
```

but

**Properties order in objects is not guaranteed in JavaScript**